# Monitor that a website is active from SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server

I want to test a portion of my website to see if it is running by executing a SQL server agent job.  my site logs every time someone loads the login page.  What I would like to do is launch:

https://www.example.com/Main/main_dir.wp1

after a few seconds run 
SELECT * FROM dbo.TR_Weblog where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, date_time, getdate()) < 1

If there are no entries the site is down.

How do I launch a URL from inside agent?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this isn't an appropriate use of SQL Agent; it's not a general purpose task scheduler.

If you're going use Agent though...

I would advise against doing it the way @TheGameiswar suggests, as it will leave orphaned `iexplore.exe` processes on your SQL Server box, and there are situations where it won't even start properly - causing the process to stall out.

Instead, make your first step one of type PowerShell, and run the following command from it:

```
invoke-restmethod -URL YOURURLHERE
```

However, this will not parse/execute any JavaScript on the page, nor load any images. It'll just pull the raw HTML returned by the page when loaded.

But even this is a bit of a Rube Goldberg method of monitoring your website's availability when there are purpose-built applications/tools and services to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select command type as cmd type and then use below url..

```
@START http://bing.com/
```

further ,you don't have any control after launch.So I think the best way is to do a periodic check of iis logs using log parser and see status